# How to do single-bit bitwise logic operation in C

Tags: c, boolean-operations

Basically, I want to do single-bit bitwise logic operation in C that is basically binary boolean algebra. But it seems that in C,

```
unsigned int a = 0;
unsigned int c = ~a;
```

results in variable c exploding.

What should I do?

Edit: I just realized that ~ Was the problem. My intention is, basically making inverting a single bit.

Comment: How does it explode? what's the value you get in c?  You must get c == 1.

Comment: *exploding*? I've never seen that happening, even with UB.

Comment: You mean you don't have a standards-compliant compiler that is wired to a stick of dynamite in case it encounters silly code like `i = ++i`?

Comment: Well, it is simple. there are no single bit data types in C. Hence you cannot perform any single bit operation in C. Actually, most of the architectures does not support bit access in hardware. So how can you expect to do it in software. However there are some microcontrollers (AVR arch based, for example) which do support SBI and CLI instructions to set or clear single bit. You can try on that, obviously at the assembly level.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild Then what would be the simple way to fix this problem?

Comment: Which problem? Your explosion isn't reproducible, at least for me. What do you expect `c` to be?

Comment: @DontYouWorryChild there are single bit values. `struct { unsigned int a: 1; unsigned int b: 1; unsigned int c; } x = { 0, 1 };  x.c = x.a | x.b;`. Arguable whether you consider them to have a single bit type.

Comment: @MattMcNabb : Still in hardware they are represented with 32 bits only, and as far as I know, complete 32-bit memory access takes place for modifying even a single bit.

Answer (score 2):

$ cat pru.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0;
    unsigned int b = 1;
    unsigned int c = a | b;

    printf("a = %u; b = %u; c = %u\n", a, b, c);
} /* main */
```

$ pru

```
a = 0; b = 1; c = 1
```

Comment: What question are you even answering?? There is no answerable question here, unless OP edits his post.

Comment: I just exposed mi compiler not exploding at all.  As there is no clear question, perhaps some right code can put things in order.  There's not even a complete coding example to work in.  So the mistake is probably at the asker desktop and he has not seen it up to now.